# Вставка файла из буфера GUI

Tags: java, gui, clipboard

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать возможность вставки скопированного в системный буфер обмена файла. Копирую так:

```
public static void copyToSysClipboard(String file) {
    File f = new File(file);
    listOfFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    listOfFiles.add(f);

    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    ClipboardFiles clipboardFiles = new ClipboardFiles(listOfFiles);
    clipboard.setContents(clipboardFiles, clipboardFiles);
}
```

Средствами винды, скопированный таким образом файл можно вставить.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Выполнить операцию Вставка
Transferable content = clipboard.getContents(clipboardFiles);
String data;
try {
  data = (String) content.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
  System.out.println(data);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```